# Node.js контекст в Class

Tags: node.js, классы, context, this

Допустим есть класс Foo, который поднимает http сервер:

```
const http = require("http");

class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  listen(port) {
    http.createServer(this.handler).listen(port);
  }

  handler(req, res) {
    console.log(this.bar);
  }
}


new Foo("test").listen(3000);
```

В handler'е (обработчике запросов к серверу) должны использоваться поля этого класса, но в данном случае, в handler, контекст this указывает на экземпляр http, а не на Foo и this.bar соответственно вернет undefined.

Можно поправить это двумя способами:

1. Добавить в конструктор `this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);`
2. В методе `listen()` сделать `http.createServer((req, res) => this.handler(req, res)).listen(port);`

Но ходят слухи, что bind плохо влияет на производительность, а второй способ - очевидный костыль. Как в мире Node.js принято поступать в подобных случаях?

Мне хотелось бы знать, как правильно управлять контекстом с точки зрения производительности в Node.js. Повлияет ли на производительность bind в конструкторе? Или может быть стоит писать всё функциями а не классами?

Comment: Не совсем так. Я понимаю почему это происходит и я знаю как это поправить. Вопрос в том, как лучше сделать это с точки зрения производительности, причем применительно к node, а не к браузерному js.

Comment: никакой разницы нет - v8 и там и там

Comment: Почему стрелочная функция костыль?

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо, но даже в этом случае остаётся куча вопросов: например как лучше биндить метод, в конструкторе класса или прямо в createServer. Или рациональнее переписать без использования класса, чтобы в createServer передавалсь простая функция.

Comment: @Alex Sazonov, мне показалось немного странным вот так вот "проксировать" функцию: вызывать одну функцию из другой только для сохранения контекста. Или это нормальная практика? Что лучше - такой подход или bind?

Comment: @posix я стрелочными пользуюсь везде, где можно. Зачем мне байнды лепить? :) Не костыль, а вполне рабочий инструмент.

Comment: @AlexSazonov, в большинстве случаев ты на заметишь разницы

Comment: @AlexSazonov, второй способ, когда ты делаешь обертку из стрелочной функции - по сути тот же bind

Comment: @Grundy верно. Но я имел ввиду, что не вообще везде тулю стрелки к месту и не к месту, а где можно избежать таким образом вещей типа байндов, то грех не пользоваться :) Почитал твой ответ про контекст. Благодарствую за развёрнутое объяснение :)

Comment: @AlexSazonov, кстати, я похоже вместо автора тебя указал в комментарии про разницу :-) странно

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо, вроде бы уложил всё в голове.